# Python: Detect word from string and also find its location

Tags: python, indexing, split

I am new to python and want to make a simple program that prints back your name and preposition in James Bond style.

So if the name contains any prepositions, such as 'Van', 'Von', 'De' or 'Di', I want the program to print it as:

```
{Preposition} {LastName}, {FirstName} {Preposition} {LastName} *edited
```

For this, I understand we need a list of the users name and of the prepositions.

```
a = [user input separated with the .split function]
b = [list of prepositions]
```

In order to find the instance of a preposition in the name, I found that the code bellow could be used:

```
if any(x in a for x in b):
```

However, I encountered a problem when trying to print the name, seeing as the preposition could be any from the aforementioned (list b). I can not find a way to print without knowing this and its location in the string. First I thought the .index function could be used, but it seems to only be capable of searching for one word, not several as needed here. The closest I can get is:

```
name_split.index('preposition1') # works
name_split.index('preposition1', 'preposition2', etc.) # does not work
```

**So what I'm asking is** if there is a way to check if any of the words from a list (b) is used in an inputted text, and also get the location of said word.

Hope I was able to explain it properly, and that someone could lend me some assistance. In advance; thank you.

Comment: you could loop through a and just check if in b, if so print or store name. `for name in a: if name in b: print name ...` You print or store on each iteration this way without having to also determine where the proposition occurs separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a better way of doing this than using the `for` loop:

```py
pattern = "{1} {2}, {0} {1} {2}"
prepositions = ['van', 'von', 'de', 'di']

# (optional) 'lower' so that we don't have to consider cases like 'vAn'
name = "Vincent van Gogh".lower()
index = -1  # by default, we believe that we did not find anything
for preposition in prepositions:
    # 'find' is the same as 'index', but returns -1 if the substring is not found
    index = name.find(preposition)
    if index != -1:
        break  # found an entry

if index == -1:
    print("Not found")
else:
    print("The index is", index,
          "and the preposition is", preposition)
    print(pattern.format(*name.split()))
```

Outputs:

```
The index is 8 and the preposition is van
van gogh, vincent van gogh
```

If you want to iterate through the list of names then you could do that:

```py
pattern = ...
prepositions = ...
names = ...

for name in names:
    name = name.lower()
    ... # the rest is the same
```

---

New version with the second type of prepositions (`"Jr.", "Sr."`):

```py
def check_prepositions(name, prepositions):
    index = -1

    for preposition in prepositions:
        index = name.find(preposition)
        if index != -1:
            break  # found an entry

    return index, preposition


patterns = [
    "{1} {2}, {0} {1} {2}",
    "{1}, {0} {1} {2}"
]

all_prepositions = [
    ['van', 'von', 'de', 'di'],
    ["Jr.", "Sr."]
]

names = ["Vincent van Gogh", "Robert Downey Jr.", "Steve"]

for name in names:
    for pattern, prepositions in zip(patterns, all_prepositions):
        index, preposition = check_prepositions(name, prepositions)

        if index != -1:
            print("The index is", index,
                  "and the preposition is", preposition)
            print(pattern.format(*name.split()))
            break

    if index == -1:
        print("Not found, name:", name)
```

Outputs:

```py
The index is 8 and the preposition is van
van Gogh, Vincent van Gogh
The index is 14 and the preposition is Jr.
Downey, Robert Downey Jr.
Not found, name: Steve
```

Comment: @Daniel if this answer helped you or you like it, please do not forget to [vote up and mark the answer as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Daniel I have updated my answer according to your question

Comment: @Daniel I added a second type of prepositions as in your comment

Comment: I hope you @Daniel can [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

Why does it matter what preposition you find in the name? You aren't printing it anywhere, all you really care about is the *last name*, and the *rest of the name*. Instead of looking for a preposition, you could simply split from the right using [`rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit), and ask for a `maxsplit` of 1. For example:

```
>>> "Vincent van Gogh".rsplit(" ", 1)
['Vincent van', 'Gogh']

>>> "James Bond".rsplit(" ", 1)
['James', 'Bond']
```

Then, you could simply print those values as you see fit.

```
fname, lname = input_name.rsplit(" ", 1)
print(f"{lname}, {fname} {lname}")
```

With `input_name = "Vincent van Gogh"`, this prints `Gogh, Vincent van Gogh`. With `input_name = "James Bond"`, you get `Bond, James Bond`.

This has the added advantage that it also works if people input a middle name / initial.

```
>> fname, lname = "Samuel L. Jackson".rsplit(" ", 1)
>> print(f"{lname}, {fname} {lname}")
Jackson, Samuel L. Jackson
```

Note that there are *lots* of oddities in how people write names, so it's worth taking a look at [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Apologies. What I meant to print was  {Preposition} {LastName}, {FirstName} {Preposition} {LastName}, which is now edited in the original question. In other words, the print would be "van Gogh, Vincent van Gogh". I also meant to use the answers I got here as inspiration to further improve the code for the use of "Jr.", "Sr.", or any roman numerals in the name, which could look like this:  {LastName}, {FirstName} {LastName} {Jr.}

Answer (score 1):

Different approach using regular expressions (I know).

```
import re

def process_input(string: str) -> str:
    string = string.strip()
    # Preset some values.
    ln, fn, prep = "", "", ""

    # if the string is blank, return it
    # Otherwise, continue.
    if len(string) > 0:

        # Search for possible delimiter.
        res = re.search(r"([^a-z0-9-'\. ]+)", string, flags = re.I)

        # If delimiter found...
        if res:
            delim = res.group(0)

            # Split names by delimiter and strip whitespace.
            ln, fn, *err = [s.strip() for s in re.split(delim, string)]
     
        else:
            # Split on whitespace
            names = [s.strip() for s in re.split(r"\s+", string)]

            # If first, preposition, last exist or first and last exist.
            # update variables.
            # Otherwise, raise ValueError.
            if len(names) == 3:
                fn, prep, ln = names
            elif len(names) == 2:
                fn, ln = names
            else:
                raise ValueError("First and last name required.")

        # Check for whitespace in last name variable.
        ws_res = re.search(r"\s+", ln)
        if ws_res:
            # Split last name if found.
            prep, ln, *err = re.split(r"\s+", ln)
        
        # Create array of known names.
        output = [f"{ln},", fn, ln]

        # Insert prep if it contains a value
        # This is simply a formatting thing.
        if len(prep) > 0:
            output.insert(2, prep)

        # Output formatted string.
        return " ".join(output)

    return string


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Loop until q called or a max run amout is reached.
    re_run = True
    max_runs = 10

    while re_run or max_runs > 0:
        print("Please enter your full name\nor press [q] to exit:")
        user_input = input()
        if user_input:
            if user_input.lower().strip() == "q":
                re_run = False
                break

            result = process_input(user_input)
            print("\n" + result + "\n\n")
            max_runs -= 1
```